# I would like to convert PDF to Post Script

Tags: pdf, postscript

I would like to convert PDF to Post Script or else is there any possible to generate post script from RDLC report in C#.net

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript and Poppler can both take PDF as input and produce PostScript, I suspect other libraries can do so as well. Have you tried Google ?

Comment: Thank you for you information. Yes. I googled it. But still I did not get any information.

Comment: Google on "PDF to PS" returned me any number of hits, including several on Stack Overflow questions. I did also point you two other specific conversion solutions, Ghostscript and Poppler, a Google search for either of those again produces numerous hits.